# Display variable value in escaped Laravel blade template code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using this code in order to display it without execution in Laravel template:

```
@{{ Ads::Display('ad_id') }}
```

Is it possible to display real value of ad_id part?

This won't work for instance:

```
@{{ Ads::Display('$ad->slug') }}
```

Comment: I'm interested in the usecase - to display the function instead of execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have use plain PHP for that:

```
{{ Ads::Display('<?php echo $ad->slug; ?>') }}
```

The @ sign is redundant, the code works without it

Comment: That's correct. Thank you. Waiting to accept the answer.

Comment: btw the @ sign is redundant, the code works without it. That's probably because of using raw php code

Comment: @mpet Thanks for the edit. Apparently it's not necessary. Probably things like `<?php` are excluded from blade parsing somehow...

Answer (score -2):

For Laravel 4 use

```
@{{ {{{  Ads::Display('ad_id') }}} }}
```

and for Laravel 5 use

```
@{{ {!!  Ads::Display('ad_id') !!} }}
```